# Listview, Webview or ? to create a tournament draw

Tags: android, listview, webview, tournament

I am wondering what the best way to render a tournament draw (scrollable) might be for Android.

Since I am new to this, I was not sure whether to invest time creating a `ListView` sort of thing or dynamically building HTML pages and rendering them with `WebView`. Or I could plop everything into a regular scrollable text view, perhaps.

The main requirement is that I would need the tournament participants to be individually clickable.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using a WebView if possible. Using a ScrollView with a ListView should be sufficient for what you're looking to do.